# Issue of quicklisp with clisp on Windows 7

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime, clisp, quicklisp

I installed quicklisp/slime/clisp on windows 7.
When I started slime with `M-x slime`, I got this error message.

[image]

I could enter 'continue' to start the clisp/slime, but this message pops up whenever I start slime.
What's wrong with this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used clisp 2.44 which was outdated for quicklisp, when I installed and use [2.49](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clisp/files/latest/download), the issue is gone.

See [`EXT:PROBE-PATHNAME`](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/dir-is-not-file.html)